# Probability question..........

Tags: probability

Assume the events are independent.

The probabilities that two students will show up for class are 0.5 and 0.7. Find the following probabilities.
(a) At least one shows up for class.

I know this is .85

(b) At least one does not show up for class.

How can I find this?

Comment: What do you know about complements of events? :)

Comment: If you can solve the first one, the probability each won't show is $(1-.5)$ and $(1-.7)$.  You can then solve it the same way as the first problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take students $A,B$. Let $P(A) = 0.5$ and $P(B)=0.7$.

So the probability of $A$ not showing up is $1-0.5=0.5$ and the probability of $B$ not showing up is $1-0.7=0.3$.

We have 4 possibilities:
$A,B$ Show up: $0.5 \cdot 0.7 = 0.35$
$A$ shows up, $B$ does not: $0.5 \cdot 0.3 = 0.15$.
$B$ shows up, $A$ does not: $0.7 \cdot 0.5 = 0.35$.
$A,B$ do not show up: $0.3 \cdot 0.5 = 0.15$.

So then the probability of at least one showing up is $0.35+0.15+0.35=0.85$, your answer there is correct. We just added all the possibilities in which one of $A,B$, or both show up.

The probability of at least one not showing up is, similarly, $0.15+0.35+0.15= 0.65$. (Add the three relevant possibilities: $A$ shows up, $B$ does not; $B$ shows up, $A$ does not, $A,B$ do not show up.)